# Zend - cannot find loader.php, following tutorial in book but using ZF2 not ZF1

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am following a tutorial in a book, but I've just realised that the book uses ZF1 and I am using ZF2. I don't want to start using ZF1, but I'm struggling to get the tutorial started.

The code:

```
require_once('Zend/Autoload.php');
Zend_Loader::registerAutoload();
```

produces the following error:

```
Warning: require_once(Zend/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/me/Sites/phpweb20/htdocs/index.php on line 2
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Zend/Autoload.php' (include_path='.:/Users/me/Sites/phpweb20/include:/Users/me/pear') in /Users/me/Sites/phpweb20/htdocs/index.php on line 2
```

I've had a trawl around the net but can't find what I should be replacing this with. Can anybody help?

Also, if I continue to follow this tutorial, am I going to be repeatedly getting stuck due to changes in syntax and classes?

Comment: ZF1 is not ZF2. Get a book about ZF2 or read the online tutorial at http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/user-guide/overview.html

Comment: it's like trying to learn English from a Japanese book, look at some ZF2 guides.

Answer (score 0):

Although the frameworks share the same name, ZF2 is vastly different from ZF1. You will undoubtedly run into more problems following resources focusing on ZF1.

ZF2 has now out of beta for many months and the documentation (and a very good tutorial) can be found at: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/index.html